# Manual install of JCL/JVCL in Delphi 10.1 Berlin

Tags: delphi, jvcl, delphi-10.1-berlin

I haven't upgraded Delphi since 2007.  I have an evaluation copy of 10.1 Berlin installed, good for another 15 days.  I want to see how difficult it will be to update a project I have to 10.1 before buying.

I've heard that in 10.0 Seattle, you could install the JCL/JVCL via GetIt.  Doesn't seem to be available yet for 10.1.  Its not even available as an official release of JCL/JVCL for 10.1. But, it does seem that the current daily builds do support 10.1.  Problem is, I only have the evaluation copy which doesn't allow command line compiling. I thought I should be able to do a manual install though.

I seemed to have manually installed a recent daily build of JCL.  However, when I try to do a manual build of JVCL, it get an error "required package 'jcl'  not found".  But, the JCL240.BPL is built and installed and in the folder that it is supposed to be in.  Specifically, I was trying to build JvCore240.bpl when I get that error.

What might be wrong? Will I just have to wait until it is available on GetIt?  And if so, any guesses when that might be?

Comment: Be sure that JCL.dcp can be found by the compiler. Update the search path so it can be found.

Comment: JediVCL provided pre-compiled installer download for the no-DCC Delphi versions. But not Jedi CodeLib it seems

Comment: http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JCL_Installation#Installation_for_Turbo_Delphi

Comment: I seemed to have manually installed...  - try to open in IDE and compile `c:\Delphi\Libs\JCL\jcl\install\JediInstaller.dpr` and then close the IDE and run the compiled installer to do automatic install `c:\Delphi\Libs\JCL\jcl\bin\JediInstaller.exe`

Comment: Hey, Rudy, that was the issue!  Thanks!  Still a dentist?  I used to hang out in the old Borland newsgroups and remember you posted about a million posts a day.

Comment: why should he ever drop the work that gives him enough money to spend much of time over his Delphi hobby? ;-)

Comment: @Arioch'The: That won't work. The trial version of Delphi doesn't include the command line compiler, and the JEDI installer uses that to compile during the install process.

Comment: Once you get beyond the JCL, the JVCL has considerable other problems (eg., `Cannot access private symbol` in several helper classes).

Comment: @KenWhite I have downloaded from github. But when I run the .bat : Using Embarcadero RAD Studio 10.1 This version of the product does not support command line compiling. Launching JCL Installer .... windows can not find "bin\JediInstaller.exe".  Is Starter edition also doesn't have command line compiler ?

Comment: @Bianca: No, Starter doesn't include the command-line compiler either. You need at least Professional.

Comment: If somebody want to install JEDI using installers, the Berlin 10.1 installers are available for both JVC and JVCL on codecentral.embarcadero.com  Both installed in my system without a problem. They are in the Delphi / Binaries section.